# Select all Rows except first row

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to get this output of selecting all except the first one to work with "OFFSET". This is the one suggested as I googled

```
SELECT merchantid, upload_num, photosrc FROM clinics_images
WHERE merchantid = 3
OFFSET 1 ROWS
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 1 ROWS LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Any alternativesto put in the SQL for this to work?

Comment: im using phpmyadmin

Comment: Is the `MerchantID` unique? Does it follow any order like increment order for eg., 1,2,3 ...? If so you can do without `LIMIT offset`

Answer (score 4):

Your error indicates that you use

```
OFFSET 1 ROWS LIMIT 0, 25
```

to get 25 records skipping the first one. The correct syntax is

```
SELECT merchantid, upload_num, photosrc 
FROM clinics_images
WHERE merchantid = 3
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 1
```

or shorter

```
LIMIT 1, 25
```

Comment: any chance i can do this without a limit?

Comment: No, But you can set a very high limit like: `limit 1, 99999999`

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from TableName order by Id offset 1 rows
```

Comment: You should add more details in the answer, perhaps explain what the OP did wrong in their query and how the solution provided by you fixes that error.